# if querystring value exists remove param and reset url

Tags: javascript, jquery

my url looks something like this

/myurl?code1=abcde&code2=fghijk&code3=lmnop&code4=qrstu&code5=vwxyz  (up to max of 5 code variables)

I have an onclick event where I get the code variable, eg in example above it returns 'fghijk', but I don't know the param, eg code2. So I want to do two things:

**1)** find and remove the param & value from my url (if my onclick variable returns 'fghijk', in the above example my url becomes, /myurl?code1=abcde&code3=lmnop&code4=qrstu&code5=vwxyz)

**2)** after this I want to reset the param numbers so that my code params are sequential beginning from 1, so after number 1 above executes my url should become /myurl?code1=abcde&code2=lmnop&code3=qrstu&code4=vwxyz

```
$('.myelement').on('click', function() {
  var url = $('.myelement a').attr('href');
  var codevar = $('.myelement span').text();
  if(url +'contains('+codevar+')') {
   // strip the param and variable from the url here

   // now reset the url so code params are in number sequence
  }

});
```

Comment: Can I get an update, did you resolve your issue or are you still having errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
$('.myelement').on('click', function() {
  var url = $('.myelement a').attr('href');
  var codevar = $('.myelement span').text();
  if(url.match(codevar)) {
   var queryString = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
   var params = queryString.split("&");
   var codeIndex = 1;
   var newQuery = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
     if (!params[i].match(codevar)) {
       newQuery += params[i].replace(/code[0-9]/, "code" + codeIndex);
       codeIndex++;
       if (i < params.length - 1) {
         newQuery += "&";
       }
     } 
   }
   url = url.replace(queryString, newQuery).replace(/&$/, ""); //new query string with the sequential parameters
  }

});
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: this works well, in my example I'm left with a trailing "&" and if I remove the last variable from the url, I'm left with a ? on the end of my url, how can I remove this if its the last one?

Answer (score 1):

```
  var codevar = 'fghijk';
  var url = $('.myelement a').attr('href');
  var param = '&'+url.substring(url.indexOf('?')+1);
  url = url.substring(0,url.indexOf('?')+1);
  if(param.indexOf(codevar) > -1) {
      var arr = param.split("&code");
      param = '';
      for(var i = 1;i<arr.length;i++){
          if(codevar == arr[i].substring(2))
              arr.splice(i, 1);
          param += 'code'+i+'='+arr[i].substring(2);
          if(i != arr.length-1)
              param +='&';
      }
      $('.myelement a').attr('href',url+param);
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/b9Hmb/1/

Comment: almost there, it works until I get to the last variable, then I get arr[i] is undefined, any ideas?

Comment: @uknowit2 Does this error show up in my fiddle?  Can you create a fiddle with your code?  You could try doing `;i<arr.length-1` instead of `;i<arr.length` in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the url with the param as key.

```
var el = $('.myelement'),
    out = $("#output");

el.on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var href = el.find("a").prop("href"),
        param = el.find("span").text(),
        idx = href.indexOf(param),
        arr = [], url;

    if (idx > -1) {
        arr = href.split(param);  // split href[0] param href[1]
        url = arr.join("mynewvalue");
        out.text(url);
    }
});
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/tive/EAsw3/